# How to design the test automation script flow when each class is dependent on the other in which all the classes have update and delete operation?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am working in a selenium project with PageFactory implementation.
I have created a test suite which contain three class with single test method in each. Each class have two validation to be done -Insertion and Deletion. Since each class has dependencies I cannot execute the script in the order in which insertion and deletion of the class A cannot be done one after other. 
In my framework I will be flushing the values stored in the class when I call driver.quit() method in the @AfterClass method.

What should be the approach in order to keep the boolean variables alive and to design the script effectively ?

Given below is the structure of the test suite:

```
Class A
@Test
public void classA_Validation()
{
        INSERTION VALIDATION --->Boolean Insert
        DELETION VALIDATION  --->Boolean Delete

            Final OutPut of Class A  --->Insert && Delete;
}

Class B
@Test
public void classB_Validation()
{
        INSERTION VALIDATION --->Boolean Insert
        DELETION VALIDATION  --->Boolean Delete

        Final OutPut of Class B  --->Insert && Delete;

}
Class C
@Test   
public void classC_Validation()
{
        INSERTION VALIDATION --->Boolean Insert
        DELETION VALIDATION  --->Boolean Delete

            Final OutPut of Class C  --->Insert && Delete;
}
```

Comment: I am unable to get what exactly do you want here?

Do you want to run Class A multiple times in a row without running Class B or C?

Why do you need the result generated after running a class(boolean variable) or test for the next execution?

Comment: You can flush the values in AfterSuite method instead of AfterClass so the values are available throughout a program execution.

But if you need those values for next execution also, then you will need to store the values somewhere and fetch them in next run.

Comment: @BludShot Yes exactly, The store mechanism is what I'm asking for ?

Comment: @BludShot Initally I designed the testcase flow to execute and validate class A then switch to class B. But if I do delete operation in class A then I cannot execute class B because class A and B are depend each other. So what I need to do is execute insertion operation of class A and store the result to any variable and then navigate to class B do both insertion and deletion in class B then again navigate to class A and execute the delete operation. So in that case how will I store the result of insertion operation in class A before navigating to class B ?